# How to filter meeting invitations/updates into a separate folder in MS Outlook?

Tags: macos, ms-office, calendar

I get a lot of meeting invites and would like to move them to a separate Outlook folder. How can I do this in Outlook 2016 for Mac?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wanting to do this before or after you've accepted/declined them? That is, are you just wanting a rule to move them into a folder when they first arrive, or are you wanting to move them after you've dealt with them?

Comment: @Monomeeth I want everything that's a calendar event to go into a separate folder - accepted, declined, meeting update, etc

Answer (score 1):

[image: Late I know, but adding this here as I ended up on this question while trying to answer my own]

Late I know, but adding this here as I ended up on this question while trying to answer my own. Type -> Invitation, Move to -> Destination folder